# How does RubyInstaller come to know the path of MSYS2?

Tags: ruby, windows, msys2, rubyinstaller

I wanted to play around with the latest Ruby on windows, so I installed the [MSYS2 toolkit](http://www.msys2.org/) first. After this I ran the [RubyInstaller](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) for version 2.4.2 and it was able to find out that MSYS2 is already installed on my system.

I checked in the environment variables, if there is an entry for the same, to my surprise there was no such entry. I also tried to search in the windows registry, but didn't found any clue.

Can someone explain me how RubyInstaller is handling that?

Comment: I believe it simply checks `C:\msys32` folder.

Comment: Actually, I was expecting the file name where this is written.

Comment: This is actually a often asked question. RubyInstaller looks for MSYS2 at every ruby start in several different directories. It's best visible by looking into the [implementation here](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/blob/rubyinstaller-2.5.1-1/lib/ruby_installer/build/msys2_installation.rb#L32-L69).

Answer (score 1):

You can check in cmd or powershell for its path as:

```
>where msys2
```

or search within all environment variables as sometimes limited entries could be shown over system properties as:

```
> $ENV:PATH
```

If its not found,then for x86_64 package of MSYS2

Set environment **PATH** to `C:\msys64\usr\bin`

Comment: Please read the question carefully, it's already working without entry in the PATH.